# Get paths of folders that contain files of specific format using a .bat script

Tags: batch, batch-file, search

I have a folder (let's say D:\Folder) that contains 2k+ folders that may or may not contain subfolders.

I need to locate those folders that contain a .zip and .jpg or .png file, so the output should be a .txt with paths of those folders.

I don't know if there is a software or tool that allows doing that easily, but from what I have read, a .bat script should be the easier option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean (.zip AND .jpg) OR (.zip AND .png)?? Clarify the logic.

Comment: @drmoishe-pippik, yes, it is [(.zip AND .jpg) OR (.zip AND .png)], sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bath
@echo off

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`%__AppDir__%where.exe /r "D:\Folder" *.zip
`)do dir /b/a-d "%%~dpi\*"|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /e "\.png \.jpg" >nul && (
         echo\%%~dpi >>"X:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Output\File.txt" )
```

---

- An alternative that will create the file (file.txt) on its first run, and overwrite (totally) on the second run, and "escape" possible special characters if present in the folder names:

```bath
@echo off

(for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`;%__AppDir__%where.exe /r "D:\Folder" *.zip`
    )do dir /b/a-d "%%~dpi\*"|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /e "\.png \.jpg" >nul && (
        echo\&<nul set/p .="%%~dpi"))>"X:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Output\File.txt"
```

---

List your zip files recursively, where a zip is found, list all files again, and if any `.png` or `.jpg` are in this folder, echo the path of the folder where the zip was found.

---

## Additional Resources:

- **[`Where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**
- **[`For` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[`For /F` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm. And thank you for the tutorials, gotta learn more about it, seeing how helpful it can be.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for your actions, especially for testing. d:)

Comment: @It Wasn't Me: why do you use %__AppDir__% if windows checks automatically for files in the system folder?

Comment: @RicardoBohner If the current user have no admin access, and are using the bat/commands on server version, you possibly get no access to the items in path variable, or path variable is incomplete for security restrictions... experience bro!

Comment: ah ok got it now